# How to know whether TrustyOS is running in Android mobile or not

Tags: security

I'm referring TEE(Trusted Execution Environment) for Android [Here](https://source.android.com/security/trusty). Can anybody help me to check whether any device is runnning Android along with Trusty OS?

Comment: This question on Stack overflow may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515838/client-application-and-trusted-application-in-trusted-execution-environment-tee

Answer (score 0):

There is this app on Github - [tee-checker](https://github.com/ctz/tee-checker/releases/tag/v4), it's [latest version](https://github.com/ctz/tee-checker/releases/tag/v4) is 3 years old (!) but it detects TEE on Qualcomm devices.

On my MiA1 it shows

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

(Click to enlarge)